# Append a json Object to the last Array in another json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, concatenation

I am currently working on a CSV parser that converts the subsequent csv to one whole JSON object. The final format needs to look like this:

```
{
  "label": "",
  "id": "",
  "link": "",
  "children": [
    {
      "label": "",
      "id": "",
      "link": "",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "label": "",
      "id": "",
      "link": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "",
          "id": "",
          "link": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "",
              "id": "",
              "link": "",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what i have done so far.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const filepath = "data.csv";
var csvsync = require("csvsync");
const debug = require("debug")("app");

function mainMethod(filepath) {
  var arrayToConvert = convertCSVToArray(filepath);
  mapArrayToJson(arrayToConvert);
}

mainMethod(filepath);

function convertCSVToArray(filepath) {
  var csv = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
  var csvAsArray = csvsync.parse(csv);
  return csvAsArray;
}

function mapArrayToJson(array) {
  var baseJson = createBaseJson(array[1]);
  console.log(baseJson);
  for (var i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
    fieldCount = findAmountOfFieldsinArray(array[i]);
    var json = computeAndAppendField(fieldCount, array[i], baseJson);
    console.dir(json, { depth: null });
  }
}

function computeAndAppendField(fieldCount, array, baseJson) {
  if (fieldCount - 1 === 3) {
    var json = createJsonFor3Entries(array);
    return json;
  }
  if (fieldCount - 1 === 6) {
    var json = createJsonFor6Entries(array);
    return json;
  }
  if (fieldCount - 1 === 9) {
    var json = createJsonFor9Entries(array);
    return json;
  }
}

function findAmountOfFieldsinArray(array) {
  var numbers = 0;
  var nullNumbers = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === "") nullNumbers++;
    else numbers++;
  }
  return numbers;
}

function createJsonFor3Entries(array) {
  json = {
    label: array[1],
    id: array[2],
    link: array[3],
    children: [],
  };
  return json;
}

function createJsonFor6Entries(array) {
  json = {
    label: array[1],
    id: array[2],
    link: array[3],
    children: [
      {
        label: array[4],
        id: array[5],
        link: array[6],
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  };
  return json;
}

function createJsonFor9Entries(array) {
  json = {
    label: array[1],
    id: array[2],
    link: array[3],
    children: [
      {
        label: array[4],
        id: array[5],
        link: array[6],
        children: [
          {
            label: array[7],
            ID: array[8],
            link: array[9],
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  return json;
}

function createBaseJson(array) {
  jsonParsed = {
    label: array[1],
    id: array[2],
    link: array[3],
    children: [],
  };
  return jsonParsed;
}
```

By my understanding, i have an initial JSON object that i have declared here, i then have a for loop that creates several JSON objects.

```
var baseJson = createBaseJson(array[1]);

console.log(baseJson);
```

The problem I am having is when I console.log this my outcome is several individual Json objects EG:

```
   {
  label: '',
  id: '',
  link: '',
  children: [
    {
      label: '',
      id: '',
      link: '',
      children: [
        {
          label: '',
          ID: '',
          link: '',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  label: '',
  id: '',
  link: '',
  children: [
    {
      label: '',
      id: '',
      link: '',
      children: [
        {
          label: '',
          ID: '',
          link: '',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is incorrect because the first entry is always at the top of the tree, with the following entries being children of the previous column.

My thinking is in the function computeAndAppendField, i must first create a new JSON object (which i am doing), i must then append said object onto the second to last Children array in the Json Element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is some sample csv data

```
Base URL,Level 1 - Name,Level 1 - ID,Level 1 - URL,Level 2 - Name,Level 2 - ID,Level 2 URL,Level 3 - Name,Level 3 - ID,Level 3 URL
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,,,
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,CHEESE,178975,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178975
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,COOKED MEAT & ANTIPASTI,178976,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178976
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,DAIRY & EGGS,178977,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178977
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,DESSERTS,178978,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178978
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,DRINKS,178979,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178979
https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse,THE BEST,178974,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974,FRESH,178969,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969,FISH & SEAFOOD,178980,https://groceries.morrisons.com/browse/178974/178969/178980
,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: In order to help, could you share some sample csv content you need to transform to json?

Comment: Sure i have added it!

Comment: please explain what is the criteria you follow to convert the example csv to the json structure you showed